# How to receive attachments from users

Tags: c#, botframework

How do I receive an attachment from a user? I've tried iterating through the Attachment object to extract the content of attachments, but it's always null:

```
foreach(var item in message.Attachment) { var content = item.Content; }
```

How can I get attachments from users are prompting them for one?

Comment: Well, the property name is `Attachments`. but I guess that's a typo. What channel are you using? The FB channel definitely sends attachments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look to the [Receive Attachment](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-ReceiveAttachment)  sample. There you will find the code required to access to the attachments sent by the users.